# Find $\bigcap_{m=0}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}$ and $\bigcup_{m=0}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m} $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> For $ n,m \in \Bbb N $, $A_{n,m}=\left\{   x \in \Bbb R: n^2 \le x<m^2+(n+1)^2 \right\}$, find
>   $$\bigcap_{m=0}^{\infty}  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}$$
>   $$\bigcup_{m=0}^{\infty}  \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}.$$

I suppose that $\bigcap_{m=0}^{\infty}  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}=R^{+}$
and $\bigcup_{m=0}^{\infty}  \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m} = \emptyset $.

Comment: They are correct, but what is the question?

Comment: to designate $\bigcap_{m=0}^{\infty}  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m} \\
 \bigcup_{m=0}^{\infty}  \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m} $

Comment: and how can i show that it is right?

Comment: I suspect that you mean something like find, or compute. I've edited accordingly, but feel free to change it if you meant something else.

Comment: yes, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First result: For any $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$[n^2, (n+1)^2[\subseteq A_{n,m}$$

$$\implies \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}[n^2, (n+1)^2[  \subseteq\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}$$
$$\implies R^{+} \subseteq\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}$$
$$\implies \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m} = R^{+}$$ for all $m$. Then you intersect $R^{+}$ with itself for all $m$ and you get your first result.

Second result: We take a given $m \in \mathbb{N}$. We want to find $n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A_{{n_1},m} \bigcap A_{{n_2},m} = \emptyset$. All you have to do is pick $n_1 = 0$ and $n_2 = m+1$ : $$A_{{0},m} \bigcap A_{{m+1},m} = [0, m^2 + 1[ \bigcap [(m+1)^2, m^2 + (m+2)^2[ = \emptyset$$
The union of an infinity of empty sets is still  an empty set so you get your second result.

Answer (score 1):

We first show that any positive number belongs to $\bigcap_{m=0}^{\infty}  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}$. Notice that any positive number lies always between two consecutive perfect squares i.e. $$\forall x>0\qquad\exists N\qquad N^2\le x<(N+1)^2$$therefore $$N^2\le x<(N+1)^2\le m^2+(N+1)^2$$which means that for all $m\in \Bbb N^*$ we have $x\in A_{n,m}$ for some $n$ therefore $x\in B_m=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}$ and this means that $x\in \bigcap_{m=0}^{\infty}  B_m=\bigcap_{m=0}^{\infty}  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}$. Also $0\in \bigcap_{m=0}^{\infty}  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}$ from which we obtain$$\bigcap_{m=0}^{\infty}  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}=\Bbb R^{\ge 0}$$

Second, we show that no non-negative real belongs to $\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}$ for all $m$. This can be simply proved since any real non negative number is finite and for large enough $n$ (i.e. $n^2>x$) we have $x\notin A_n$ which means that $\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}=\emptyset$. Since the union of empty sets is still an empty set we finally obtain$$\bigcup_{m=0}^{\infty}  \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m} = \emptyset $$and the proof is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in \mathbb R^{+}$ and $ m\geq 0$. Take $n=[\sqrt x]$ and verify that $n^{2}\leq x \leq m^{2}+(n+1)^{2}$. This proves the first relation. Suppose the $y$ belongs to the second set. Then there exists $m$ such that $n^{2}\leq x \leq m^{2}+(n+1)^{2}$ for all $n$. But then $n^{2} \leq x$ and $x\leq m^{2}+(1+1)^{2}$, so $n^{2} \leq m^{2}+(1+1)^{2}$ for any $n \geq 0$ which is absurd. Hence the second set is empty.

Answer (score 0):

$$B = \bigcap_{m=0}^{\infty}  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m}$$

Since $A$ is never has a negative, you can reason that $B$ doesn't either.  Proving the rest is equivalent to

$$(\forall x \in \mathbb R^{\ge 0} ~\forall m \in \mathbb N ~ \exists n \in \mathbb N)~
n^2 \le x < (n+1)^2 + m$$

So to prove it you need to give me a function $F$, of the form $n = F(x,m)$, such that if I tell you $x$ and $m$ your function tells me which $n$ it is in.  $F$ is pretty direct nothing tricky about it.

$$\bigcup_{m=0}^{\infty}  \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,m} = \emptyset$$

$$(\forall x \in \mathbb R) \lnot (\exists m \in \mathbb N ~\forall n \in \mathbb N)~
n^2 \le x < (n+1)^2 + m $$

equivalently

$$(\forall x \in \mathbb R ~ \forall m \in \mathbb N ~\exists n \in \mathbb N)~
\lnot (n^2 \le x < (n+1)^2 + m)$$

So same thing again, your proof will be demonstrating a function $F$ such that $n = F(x, m)$, but in this case it is to give a contradiction of the inequality.  If $x < 0$ it is easy,

$$n = \begin{cases} x < 0 &\quad \text{Anything} \\
                    x \ge 0 &\quad \text{To be determined}
\end{cases}$$

I suggest just pick an $n$ that is so big that $x$ can't be in range.